# How to group elements with a new element based on position?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a big amount of verses that I would like to group into stanzas (see example below). I would like to add the element `<lg>` every eight verse. How can I achieve this using XSLT?

Input:

```
 <text>
  <body>
     <l>Gozaba, juvenil, el trace Orfeo,</l>
     <l>de libre edad, la primavera ociosa,</l>
     <l>dando a sus años regalado empleo</l>
     <l>la lira dulcemente numerosa.</l>
     <l>No al vínculo legal del Himeneo</l>
     <l>afectos cede, ni a la cipria diosa,</l>
     <l>cual si anteviera el ánimo presago,</l>
     <l>ya por su medio, el venidero estrago.</l>
     <l>Ama su voz, que, en dulce melodía,</l>
     <l>de otro amor le divierte y le enajena;</l>
     <l>bien que la misma voz, con tiranía,</l>
     <l>toda hermosura libre a amar condena.</l>
     <l>Así que en unas armas poseía</l>
     <l>propia defensa, con ofensa ajena,</l>
     <l>siendo el sonoro canto, mientras pudo,</l>
     <l>del Amor flecha, y a su flecha escudo.</l>
```

Desired output:

```
<text>
 <body>
   <lg>
         <l>Gozaba, juvenil, el trace Orfeo,</l>
         <l>de libre edad, la primavera ociosa,</l>
         <l>dando a sus años regalado empleo</l>
         <l>la lira dulcemente numerosa.</l>
         <l>No al vínculo legal del Himeneo</l>
         <l>afectos cede, ni a la cipria diosa,</l>
         <l>cual si anteviera el ánimo presago,</l>
         <l>ya por su medio, el venidero estrago.</l>
</lg>
<lg>
         <l>Ama su voz, que, en dulce melodía,</l>
         <l>de otro amor le divierte y le enajena;</l>
         <l>bien que la misma voz, con tiranía,</l>
         <l>toda hermosura libre a amar condena.</l>
         <l>Así que en unas armas poseía</l>
         <l>propia defensa, con ofensa ajena,</l>
         <l>siendo el sonoro canto, mientras pudo,</l>
         <l>del Amor flecha, y a su flecha escudo.</l>
</lg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="size" as="xs:integer" select="8"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="l" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $size">
                <lg>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </lg>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```